# Invoking "cmake" failed

Tags: ros, catkin-make

I am unable to solve this problem. I tried to run catkin_make command in catkin_ws directory

```
yograj@yograj-Inspiron-5537:~/catkin_ws$ catkin_make
Base path: /home/yograj/catkin_ws
Source space: /home/yograj/catkin_ws/src
Build space: /home/yograj/catkin_ws/build
Devel space: /home/yograj/catkin_ws/devel
Install space: /home/yograj/catkin_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "cmake /home/yograj/catkin_ws/src -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/yograj/catkin_ws/devel -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/yograj/catkin_ws/install -G Unix Makefiles" in "/home/yograj/catkin_ws/build"
####
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/yograj/catkin_ws/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /opt/ros/kinetic
-- This workspace overlays: /opt/ros/kinetic
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /home/yograj/anaconda2/bin/python
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Using empy: /usr/bin/empy
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/yograj/catkin_ws/build/test_results
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/gtest': gtests will be built
-- Using Python nosetests: /usr/bin/nosetests-2.7
ImportError: "from catkin_pkg.package import parse_package" failed: No module named catkin_pkg.package
Make sure that you have installed "catkin_pkg", it is up to date and on the PYTHONPATH.
CMake Error at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/safe_execute_process.cmake:11 (message):
  execute_process(/home/yograj/anaconda2/bin/python
  "/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/parse_package_xml.py"
  "/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/../package.xml"
  "/home/yograj/catkin_ws/build/catkin/catkin_generated/version/package.cmake")
  returned error code 1
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package_xml.cmake:74 (safe_execute_process)
  /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/all.cmake:151 (_catkin_package_xml)
  /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:20 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:52 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/yograj/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/yograj/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Invoking "cmake" failed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem using the following command:-

```
pip install -U rosdep rosinstall_generator wstool rosinstall six vcstools
```

Comment: This did not take away the error `No module named catkin_pkg.package` in my case.

Answer (score 0):

catkin_create_pkg  [depend1] [depend2] [depend3]
- Just change the name of the package.There are some keywords that should not be used since it confuse the compiler. I first use  and I had an error after compiling(catkin_make). I changed it to  and it worked. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by many tries. It is not guaranteed that it will help you, in my case, this helped.

- A good start was ["No module named catkin_pkg.package" on catkin_make w/ Hydro](https://answers.ros.org/question/204024/no-module-named-catkin_pkgpackage-on-catkin_make-w-hydro/).
- The main steps are already documented at a rather neighboured thread of [Installing OpenCV fails because it cannot find “skbuild”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63448467/installing-opencv-fails-because-it-cannot-find-skbuild/65479652#65479652).

But why do I need to have `python -m pip -V` = 2.7 and be in the Python base environment in order to get rid of that error?

- The standard `python -m pip` command after having applied `sudo apt-get install python-pip` under Python 2.7 seems important. `python -V` must be `Python 2.7.17` or the like. This is probably because the catkin installer simply needs the old pip as the standard assignment, in my case in order to deal with gazebo.
- By the same time it seems important that `sudo apt-get install python3-pip` is installed as well, which is then installed automatically under Python 3.6.
- If you are in a virtual environment, the configuration of the base environment that is used by the installer is conflicting with versions that are installed in the virtual environment.

[This comment](http://lists.ros.org/pipermail/ros-users/2015-October/069721.html) of a developer already in 2015 explains why 3.6 is installed even if you have another version like 3.7 or the like installed:

> The issue you're running into is that the Python that is turned on by
> default is a non-system Python 2.6 install which is unaffected by
> installing Python packages with apt-get. By using the minimal image
> you avoid having to deal with custom versions of Python.

The old standard 2.6 has now become 3.6; if you install with apt-get, 3.6 will likely be installed. But if you install `python-pip` instead of `python3-pip`, it will use a python 2.7 version by default.

`apt-get` does not at all care about any python version that you already have. That would mean that one should install as much as possible with apt-get to avoid any Python version conflicts / have an independent install. And using pip should at best be clear by putting the needed `python -m` / `python3.7 -m` / ... in front.

Quoting something else from [catkin_make: No module named 'catkin_pkg'](https://answers.ros.org/question/340510/catkin_make-no-module-named-catkin_pkg/):

> You'll either have to install catkin_pkg (and a few others) for the
> Python 3 interpreter (using the pip3 command shown by @...),
> or make sure Catkin uses the Python 2 interpreter.
>
> My recommendation would be the latter, as the rest of Melodic will
> also have been built against Python 2. Not Python 3.
>
> The next release of ROS 1 (Noetic) will support Python 3.

This was in 2019. In 2020, Python 3 is now supported by ROS, but that does not mean that a project that has started in 2019 supports it entirely. So better keep to python2.7 for pip and most of the installations that you do for a project that has started in 2019 and has `cmake` errors.

Further ideas:

- [Invoking “cmake” failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55342640/invoking-cmake-failed) on Stack Overflow
- [Installing python3-catkin-pkg uninstalls ros-melodic-desktop packages](https://answers.ros.org/question/348505/installing-python3-catkin-pkg-uninstalls-ros-melodic-desktop-packages/)

Answer (score 0):

Delete folder catkin_ws , And do it again.

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Maxneto CH kk. Thanks for your answer but we are looking for comprehensive answers that provide some explanation and context. Very short answers cannot do this, so please edit your answer to explain why it is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed. See [answer] for more info.

Answer (score -2):

Execute the following:

```
$ pip install virtualenv
$ virtualenv <your name of choice, call it v>
$ source <your name of choice, that is v>/bin/activate
```

Running catkin_make after doing the above worked for me.

Comment: I also learned that catkin must be executed when the venv is activated, and then you start catkin in the folder where you generate the build folder. But it does not solve the issue here, I still get `No module named catkin_pkg.package`.